# How to efficiently apply an arbitrary function on a moving window in a BTreeMap

Tags: dictionary, rust, b-tree

How can I efficiently apply a function over a moving window of a `BTreeMap`, where the window is determined by a range of the key?

My current code is like this but it is horribly slow when the `BTreeMap` gets very large (and probably with increasing `radius`). I suspect it's because of the `clone()` but I can't think of an alternative solution. How do I do this efficiently?

```rust
use nalgebra::Vector3;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn get_window(data: &BTreeMap<i64, Vector3<f64>>, center: &i64, radius: &i64) -> BTreeMap<i64, Vector3<f64>> {
    let mut window = data.clone();
    window.retain(|&ts, _| ts >= (center - radius) && ts <= (center + radius));
    window
}

fn kernel(data: BTreeMap<i64, Vector3<f64>>) -> Vector3<f64> {
    // This is just an example function
    let n = data.len() as f64;
    let x = data.iter().map(|(_, vec)| vec[0]).sum::<f64>() / n;
    let y = data.iter().map(|(_, vec)| vec[1]).sum::<f64>() / n;
    let z = data.iter().map(|(_, vec)| vec[2]).sum::<f64>() / n;
    Vector3::new(x, y, z)
}

fn main() {
    let mut btreemap = BTreeMap::<i64, Vector3<f64>>::new();
    btreemap.insert(0, Vector3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    btreemap.insert(1, Vector3::new(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    btreemap.insert(2, Vector3::new(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    btreemap.insert(3, Vector3::new(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    btreemap.insert(4, Vector3::new(2.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    btreemap.insert(5, Vector3::new(0.0, 2.0, 0.0));
    btreemap.insert(6, Vector3::new(0.0, 0.0, 2.0));
    
    let mut smoothed = BTreeMap::<i64, Vector3<f64>>::new();
    for (ts, _vec) in btreemap.iter() {
        let window = get_window(&btreemap, &ts, &1);
        let kernel = kernel(window);
        smoothed.insert(*ts, kernel);
    }

    println!("{:?}", smoothed);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of cloning the map and then filtering the items in the window, you can use [`BTreeMap::range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.range) to get an iterator over the items within a range of the map. This is cheap because a [`btree_map::Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/btree_map/struct.Range.html) iterates over the data in the source map; it doesn't clone any of it.

I recommend also passing the center and radius as `i64` rather than `&i64`. There's no need to borrow them.

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::collections::btree_map;

fn get_window(data: &BTreeMap<i64, Vector3<f64>>, center: i64, radius: i64) -> btree_map::Range<'_, i64, Vector3<f64>> {
    data.range(center-radius..=center+radius)
}

fn kernel(data: btree_map::Range<'_, i64, Vector3<f64>>) -> Vector3<f64> {
    // This is just an example function
    let n = data.clone().count() as f64;
    let x = data.clone().map(|(_, vec)| vec[0]).sum::<f64>() / n;
    let y = data.clone().map(|(_, vec)| vec[1]).sum::<f64>() / n;
    let z = data.clone().map(|(_, vec)| vec[2]).sum::<f64>() / n;
    Vector3::new(x, y, z)
}
```

The loop in `main` becomes:

```
for (&ts, _vec) in btreemap.iter() {
    let window = get_window(&btreemap, ts, 1);
    let kernel = kernel(window);
    smoothed.insert(ts, kernel);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44e71ec8cacd6cff98791834f27e0e24)

Comment: I love this solution. There is probably an overall `O(n log n)` cost incurred by searching for the end-points of the range each call to `get_window`.  That could be removed by using iterators for the windows start and end,  then stepping each forward to get the next window. (But it's more complicated and you need to be careful about end conditions). Considering the cost of processing all the windows is something like `O(n m)`the look-up costs tends only to dominate when n is significantly larger than m - and so is unlikely to be an issue in "most" cases.